# Which encoder should I use with a 24V Dc motor and 6mm shaft?

Tags: motor, quadrature-encoder

I would like to control the position and velocity of a DC motor like this [one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ZY-MY-1016-Electric-Motor-24v-200w-Brushed-E-Bike-Scooter-24-Volt-200-Watt-Chain-/171573828523?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27f298dbab) (ZY MY 1016 - 24V - 10A - 200W). The motor comes with a 13 TOOTH SPROCKET and the diameter of the shaft is 6mm. It's not possible to apply an encoder to the back of the motor (see [picture](http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NDIzWDU1MA==/z/0NYAAOxyDo1TjvN6/$_12.JPG?set_id=880000500F))

The angular velocity in the description is 2750 RPM, which encoder do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of them. Which ones have you looked at?

I googled, and the first one that came up was a smaller pololu unit for a micro robot,
[image]

But you know what? They all work the same and are fairly simple to build / adapt.

You probably can locate a hall effect sensor at the 13 tooth sprocket.
[Understanding Integrated Hall Effect Rotary Encoders](http://www.sensorsmag.com/sensors/position-presence-proximity/understanding-integrated-hall-effect-rotary-encoders-1254)

Other than that, this sounds like a shopping question, you might get lucky and find someone who has used a 6mm shaft encoder and can recommend it, but that is not a robotics question.

Comment: The one you posted is designed to work with Pololu micro metal gearmotors. I was thinking about this one http://www.robot-italy.com/it/amt102-v-quadrature-encoder.html.

Comment: Unless you get very lucky, you will have to make mechanical modification to accommodate anything. But, given that, the Pololu unit could work on a car. You just have to settle on what is the least amount of work to give you what you need.

Comment: Ok I'll try with quadrature encoders and post the answer. I've used them with smaller dc motors. Maybe the 6mm adapter will work without any modification

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you will be able to simply by something an attach it.  How to make an encoder will depend on how this motor is used.  Are you doing a chain, gears?  You will need to design the rotation sensor into the rest of the power transmission system.

What you do is place a disk of some kind, plastic or metal and then you make a hole or slot in the disk and your sensor detects the slot.  The simplest sensors to use are these IR LED/photo transistors.   They are cheap and very reliable even in bright light.  I use them with a black plastic disk.  But test your disk material first.  Some that looks black is transparent in IR.  Metal is best.
[IR sensor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00843JUJM)   To use them you need to add two resisters and 5V power.  330R for a current limiter on the LED side and a 10K load resister on the transistor side.  Those values are not critical. I connect this to a interrupt pin on an Arduino.

In your case you might drill a hole in the sprocket gear and mount an IR sensor where it can "see" the hole.  The sensor come with different slot widths.  I'd pick a width abut twice the thickness of the disk